# vlookup returning n/a for SOME entries

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am having an issue with the vlookup function.

For conveniance purposes i have a table one the same sheet as my final values:

So i have columns A (short) and B (H_rate)

```
 Short  H_RATE 

PM   € 31,30 
SYS  22,75 
ME   € 21,38  
EE   € 21,38  
VSE  € 22,55  
SSE  € 20,36  
SE   € 18,36  
AT   € 18,36
TW   € 18,26  
TR   € 18,26
```

Using the formula `=VLOOKUP($E15;$A$2:$B$11;2)`

Where E15 is ME (this i have checked by doing `=E15=A4` giving `TRUE`)

vlookup returns #N/A.

If i were to change MW to PM the correct value will appear.....

What am i doing wrong

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569859/excel-vlookup-gives-wrong-value?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to add False as below

```
VLOOKUP($E15;$A$2:$B$11;2;FALSE)
```

FALSE is used to match the string "exactly" as it is displayed.